# Quickest way to find out which EPiServer version you are running on a site

Tags: episerver, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2

Are there any other places except for episerver.config where you can find out which version ("EPiServer 6" / "EPiServer 6 R2") of EPiServer the site was built on?

Usually I look in episerver.config and compare those numbers to the ones in Deployment Center to find out if it's "EPiServer 6" or "EPiServer 6 R2".

I have only been working with EPiServer 6 and EPiServer 6 R2 so those versions are the most relevant to the question.

Edit: Updated the two first paragraphs with what I mean by the word version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other have stated, the plugin manager in admin mode, or simply looking at the title of the editor/admin mode browser window shows you the version.

Also, here is a list of version numbers and their corresponding release "Name":
http://epiwiki.se/configuration/episerver-version-nummber-vs-release-number

EPiServer version number vs release number (taken from the assembly EPiServer.dll)

- 7.0.586.4 - EPiServer 7 - Patch 1
- 7.0.859.4 - EPiServer Framwork
- 7.0.586.1 - EPiServer 7
- 1.1.1239.0 - EPiServer Shared
- 7.0.859.1 - EPiServer Framwork
- 7.0.1764.1 - EPiServer Search
- 7.0.499.1 - EPiServer 7 Preview
- 6.1.379.5xx - EPiServer CMS 6 R2 (with diferent versions of general hotfix)
- 6.1.379.1 - EPiServer CMS 6 R2
- 6.0.530.0 - EPiServer CMS 6
- 5.2.375.236 - EPIServer CMS 5 R2 SP2
- 5.2.375.133 - EPiServer CMS 5 R2 SP1
- 5.2.375.7 - EPiServer CMS 5 R2
- 5.1.422.267 - EPiServer CMS 5 SP3
- 5.1.422.256 - EPiServer CMS 5 SP2
- 5.1.422.122 - EPiServer CMS 5 SP1
- 5.1.422.4 - EPiServer CMS 5
- 4.62.0.469 - EPiServer CMS 4.62B

The version numbers are built with the following pattern:

Major.release.buildnumber.days

Where:

Major - is the major version that probably has breaking changes to a previous version

Release – the release number should not include breaking changes

Buildnumber – the build number

Days – days after the build number was generated

Comment: That link is a great addition to all the info already in this question.

Comment: Marking this one as answer since Eriks link's got everything I need plus more and it's the quickest way to check for EPiServer versions if you don't know version numbers by heart.

Comment: Can you update this post with the latest EPiServer releases please?

Comment: Can you update this post with the 7.x versions please?

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest ways to see actual EPiServer versions is to look into plugin manager in admin:

[image]

- 6.0.530.0 - 6 R1
- 6.1.379.0 - 6 R2
- 7.0.586.1 - 7

Answer (score 1):

The title-tag in EPiServer Admin or Edit will show you the version you are running.

Comment: This is also a very good tip. Still doesn't tell you immediately if it's an R1 or an R2, however.

Comment: 6.0 = EPiServer 6 (R1), 6.1 = R2.. That is EPiServers fault not making so much sense in their version naming. Wait until you add R2 with Hotfix 502.. Then you have to check properties of EPiServer.dll and see if the version-property ends with .502 there.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for features when it comes to CMS 6 R1/R2. For example, the personalization features came with R2.

Comment: So you mean that this part (http://world.episerver.com/Globals/xmlrpc/20055/2010/11/20/image_4.png) of EPiServer is only available in R2? Sorry don't have access to an R1 at the moment and honestly I think I've only been in an R1 edit/admin mode once or twice.